# Declaring XML Namespace at Runtime

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, unityscript, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I’m trying to write a script for a Unity application (written in Unityscript) which is able to add nodes to an XML document at runtime (using the XmlDocument class). 
I am encountering issues when trying to declare the *'name'* attribute of the new node.

I would like to know how I can create a node with a namespace outside of the default XMLNS attribution (in my case replacing the *'xmlns='* to *'name='*) to match the existing markup.

After much time on the MSDN docs I assume this is probably to do with the **XmlNameSpaceManager** or changing the default namespace, however I am struggling to understand how to implement this (still pretty new to XML in Unity / uJS) so any advice would be very welcome.

Many thanks in advance,

Ryan

**Current code:**

```js
function Start(){
 //Automatically loads XML doc for save etc
 doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(Application.dataPath + "/objMetaTest01.xml");
 
 root = doc.DocumentElement;
 Debug.Log("XML Root: " + root.Name);
 
 nodeList = root.SelectNodes("MetaPipeObject");
 Debug.Log("***XML Log Begin ***");
 Debug.Log("Number of Objects: " + nodeList.Count); //returns total number of MPObjs
 
 for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
 {
  var node = nodeList[i];
  //Debug.Log("Node Name: " + node.Attributes["name"].Value);
  
 }
 
 //Namespace Manager to add namespace to file
 //docNameSpace = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
 //docNameSpace.AddNamespace("name", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
 
 //Debug.Log("Doc DefaultNamespace: " + docNameSpace.DefaultNamespace);
 //Debug.Log("nmsg has 'name' prefix: " + docNameSpace.HasNamespace("name"));
 Debug.Log("***XML Log End ***");
}


public function CreateNewNode(){
 //Creates new node for new objects
 //will be similar to the replace function to be written soon

 //select last MP node to add the new one behind 
 doc.DocumentElement.RemoveAttribute("xlmns");
 
 var lastObjNode = root.SelectSingleNode("MetaPipeObject[last()]");
 var newObjNode = doc.CreateElement("MetaPipeObject", "DogTest");
 
 //Create new attribute test
 //var nameAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
 //newObjNode.Attributes.Append(nameAttr);
 //"name", "nameTest", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI, doc
 
 newObjNode.InnerXml = lastObjNode.InnerXml; //copy content
 
 root.InsertAfter(newObjNode, lastObjNode); //add to the bottom of the xml doc
 
 doc.Save(Application.dataPath + "/objMetaTest01.xml");
 
 Debug.Log("New Nodes Attribute: " + newObjNode.Attributes);
 Debug.Log("New Node Namespace: " + newObjNode.NamespaceURI);
 Debug.Log("New Node Name: " + newObjNode.Name);
 Debug.Log("New node is: " + newObjNode.InnerText);
}
```

**Currently Returns**

```
   <MetaPipeObject xmlns="DogTest">
 <FileName xmlns="">water_drop.obj</FileName>
 <Description xmlns="">Text to go here</Description>
 <Health xmlns="">10</Health>
 <Experience xmlns="">10</Experience>
```

**The result I am wanting:**

```
  <MetaPipeObject name="DogTest">
 <FileName>water_drop.obj</FileName>
 <Description>Text to go here</Description>
 <Health>10</Health>
 <Experience>10</Experience>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much further research it turns out the solution to creating the desired XML format was two part and much simpler than the route I initially researched.

1. Firstly I was creating the the element using the wrong method; initially I was using the [CreateElement(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1k08cbx(v=vs.110).aspx) which was, presumably, invoking the default namespace URI (hence all of the xmlns attributes being associated to each of the child tags). The method I really wanted was the [CreateElement(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1ys7w6(v=vs.110).aspx) which simply provides the name of the element.
2. All that I needed to do was assign the name attribute via SetAttribute() and the issue was sorted.

I hope this helps anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation. The NamspaceManager is another possible route I could have used and assigned a different namespace other than the default, however to resolve my issue this seemed overkill.

Here is the snippet of code I ended up using:

```js
public function CreateNewNode(){
 //Creates new node for new objects
 //will be similar to the replace function to be written soon

 var lastObjNode = root.SelectSingleNode("MetaPipeObject[last()]"); //select last MP node to add the new one behind
 
 var newObjNode = doc.CreateElement("MetaPipeObject");
 
 //Create new attribute test
 newObjNode.SetAttribute("name", objName);

 newObjNode.InnerXml = lastObjNode.InnerXml; //copy content from above listing
 
 newObjNode.SelectSingleNode("FileName").InnerText = fileName;
 newObjNode.SelectSingleNode("Description").InnerText = "No Description Added Yet";
 newObjNode.SelectSingleNode("Health").InnerText = "0";
 newObjNode.SelectSingleNode("Experience").InnerText = "0";
 
 
 root.InsertAfter(newObjNode, lastObjNode); //add to the bottom of the xml doc
 
 doc.Save(Application.dataPath + "/objMetaTest01.xml");
 
 Debug.Log("CREATED new node: " + newObjNode.GetAttribute("name"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check following Links for help

1. [Writing XML using JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12504/Writing-XML-using-JavaScript)
2. [Create Well-Formed XML with JavaScript](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/h/2127)

Comment: Hi Umair, thanks for your response. I'm not sure we have access inside of Unity to the XMLWriter class described in your first link.
I am using the XmlDocument class implemented in the .NET framework and would like to know how to define attributes using its NameSpaceManager or SetAttribute methods; do you know how this might be achieved?